# How to append an integer to a const char value in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, append

I have SQL query statement which used to display the contents in the table. The SQL statement consist of a where clause which is to be appended with numeric value as 1 ,2 3 etc depends upon the previously selected content. I am having the numeric value as int and I want it to append to SQL statement which is const char. How can I append both the values?

My query is:

```
select * from Book where id=1;
```

I have the id value is integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply bind the parameter.  E.g.:

```
sqlite3 *db;
... // open database
sqlite3_stmt *pStmt;

sqlite3_prepare_v2(
  db,
  "select * from book where id = ?",
  -1,
  &pStmt,
  NULL
);

sqlite3_bind_int(pStmt, 1, bookId);
```

See the SQLite documentation on [compiling](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) and [binding](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) prepared statements.  You can reuse the same statement more than once.  [`sqlite3_clear_bindings`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/clear_bindings.html) lets you reset the values.

Comment: Your answer was totally incomplete when down voted. I'll reverse it now though.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Book WHERE id=%d", myInt];
```

to compose your SQL string?